# How to set "android:scrollbars=vertical" programmatically?

Tags: android

I want to dynamically set `scrollbars` in an `EditText` programmatically, but I don't find this api as setscrollbars. Could anyone tell me if this can be done programmatically?

```
android:scrollbars="vertical"
```

Is this possible? How can I achieve this programmatically?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was looking for a method to do this programatically, too.

Seems from http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android:scrollbars it's **not possible**, cause no related method is mentioned there.

The only method that sounds good by description is:

```
View.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(boolean)
```

but in my case it didn't work. But that may depend on the layout and the way it is used.

I am thinking now about having two layouts: one with the attribute set to "none" and one set to "vertical". Then in code I could decide which to use.

Comment: hi, it didn't worked for me also. please post if you have any other suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

```
    final TypedArray typedArray = context.obtainStyledAttributes(null,  new int[]{});
            try {
                Method method = View.class.getDeclaredMethod("initializeScrollbars" , TypedArray.class);
                method.invoke(this, typedArray);
            }catch (Exception e) {
            }
            typedArray.recycle();
 setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to override the android:scrollbarTrackVertical and android:scrollbarThumbVertical drawables with your own. You can do it in code or with styling.

This is a [link](http://blog.androgames.net/40/custom-button-style-and-theme/) that shows how to do custom buttons. The principle for scrollbars is similar.

Comment: i donot want to set myself stying,i want to know android:scrollbars="vertical how to using code complete.
as android:text ,ican use code  (View)setText()

Answer (score 0):

Programmatically :

```
RecyclerView mRecyclerView =rootView.findViewById(R.id.your-recycler-view);
if(mRecyclerView!=null){
  mRecyclerView.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled( true );
}
```

In the XML :

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:scrollbars="vertical"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Other scrollbars:

```
android:scrollbars="vertical"
android:scrollbars="horizontal"
android:scrollbars="vertical|horizontal"
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. In my case `android:scrollbars="vertical"` had to be in the XML for `RecyclerView.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled` to work.